# How to click on looped array element and only get it's value

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of cats and I want to alert each cat on click, all I get is if you click on cat3, cats: cat4,cat5 is getting looped as well.
How can I do it in jquery? Thank you!

```
var cats = ['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5'];
for(var i=0; i<cats.length; i++) {

var catz = cats[i];

$('body').append('<div class="catPremium">' + cats[i] + '</div>');

$('.catPremium').on('click', (function(numCopy) {
    return function() {
            alert(numCopy);
    };
})(catz));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you are registering the event handler, in each iteration you are adding the event handler to all the existing `catPremium` elements, instead of targeting only the recent one.

One easy solution is to use `.appendTo` which will return the newly created element and then add the handler to only that element.

```js
var cats = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'];
$.each(cats, function(i, cat) {

  $('<div/>', {
    text: cat,
    'class': 'catPremium'
  }).appendTo('body').on('click', function() {
    alert(cat)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Another solution

```js
var cats = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'];

cats.forEach(function(cat) {
  $('<div/>', {
    text: cat,
    'data-cat': cat,
    'class': 'catPremium'
  }).appendTo('body')
});


$(document).on('click', '.catPremium', function() {
  alert($(this).data('cat'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain how you know that method

$('<div/>', {
    text: cat,
    'data-cat': cat,
    'class': 'catPremium'
  }
exist? I bearly understand it.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.catPremium')` target all elements with catPremium class. You need attach event to last appended element only. you can use `:last` selector along with class selector to achieve this:

```
$('.catPremium:last').on('click',(function(){
    //rest code
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmy23jmp/)**